# Mymodule is not working after Installing pyinstaller standalone

Tags: python, pyinstaller, gmail-api

I am trying to install my own script into executable file, it is running okay in my ide. I  am installing a standalone Pyinstaller the dist/main.exe is not working -onefile. I am confused what is the problem any knows how to fix? big helps thank you

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data "C:/Users/aidez/PycharmProjects/Automate/CLIENT.json;." --add-data "C:/Users/aidez/PycharmProjects/Automate/gmail_email_test.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/aidez/PycharmProjects/Automate/google_drive.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/aidez/PycharmProjects/Automate/google_sheet.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/aidez/PycharmProjects/Automate/token_emails.py;."  "C:/Users/aidez/PycharmProjects/Automate/main.py"
```

Response

```
>[gmail_email_test.py](https://pastebin.com/MKdSz2DN)<br>
[google_sheet.py](https://pastebin.com/7ZQQnDku)<br>
[main.py](https://pastebin.com/3ywLGhBQ)



Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in 
_find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in 
exec_module
File "gmail_email_test.py", line 86, in <module>
EMAILS = searching_emails()
File "gmail_email_test.py", line 23, in searching_emails
results = service.users().messages().list(q="sample@.com",
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'users'
```

Comment: It looks like `service` is None for some reason. You need to share some code example because otherwise it's impossible to know what is happening

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MKdSz2DN here I tried to another computer and changing the query to a different email and it was reading the query value of his email not my own email :(